# Getting EasyMock mock objects to throw Exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm in process of using EasyMock to write Unit tests for a number of collaborating classes. One of these classes (lets call it `Foo`) opens a network connection to a remote server and parses that servers' XML response into something the rest of the classes can use.

Presently my tests only encompass scenarios in which everything is hunky-dory and the remote server is up and running and returning XML as expected. However, I *would* be happier if I could mock `Foo` so that I simulate what happens if the remote server is down, or there is some other problem that causes an `IOException` to be thrown by `Foo`.

I have had a look at the EasyMock API, and I can't see anything that looks like a method asking a mock to throw an Exception.

It's not absolutely essential for me to have `Exception` based tests, but I am curious if its possible with EasyMock, and I think it would be useful to test `Foo`'s public contract in this way.

Anyone done anything like this with EasyMock before?

**References**

- [EasyMock API](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/index.html)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-exceptions):

> For specifying exceptions (more exactly: `Throwable`s) to be thrown, the object returned by `expectLastCall()` and `expect(T value)` provides the method `andThrow(Throwable throwable)`. The method has to be called in record state after the call to the Mock Object for which it specifies the `Throwable` to be thrown.
>
> Unchecked exceptions (that is, `RuntimeException`, `Error` and all their subclasses) can be thrown from every method. Checked exceptions can only be thrown from the methods that do actually throw them.

For example:

```
expectLastCall().andThrow(new HibernateException("Something terrible happened"));

expect(query.list()).andThrow(
        new HibernateException("Something terrible happened"));
```

Comment: If anyone finds this not working for them... make sure you use EasyMock.replay

Answer (score 5):

you can use the method `andThrow(Throwable throwable)` in easy mock. Check the [documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html) - heading **Working with Exceptions**.

For example

```
 expect(mock.voteForRemoval("Document"))
    .andThrow(new RuntimeException(), 4);
```