# How can I mock a void method to throw an exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, powermock, easymock

I have a structure like this:

```
public class CacheWrapper {
    private Map<Object, Object> innerMap;

    public CacheWrapper() {
        //initialize the innerMap with an instance for an in-memory cache
        //that works on external server
        //current implementation is not relevant for the problem
        innerMap = ...;
    }

    public void putInSharedMemory(Object key, Object value) {
        innerMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public Object getFromSharedMemory(Object key) {
        return innerMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

And my client class (you could say it looks like this):

```
public class SomeClient {
    //Logger here, for exception handling
    Logger log = ...;
    private CacheWrapper cacheWrapper;
    //getter and setter for cacheWrapper...

    public Entity getEntity(String param) {
        Entity someEntity = null;
        try {
            try {
                entity = cacheWrapper.getFromSharedMemory(param);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //probably connection failure occurred here
                log.warn("There was a problem when getting from in-memory " + param + " key.", e);
            }
            if (entity == null) {
                entity = ...; //retrieve it from database
                //store in in-memory cache
                try {
                    cacheWrapper.put(param, entity);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //probably connection failure occurred here
                    log.warn("There was a problem when putting in in-memory " + param + " key.", e);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(".......", e);
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

**I'm creating unit tests for `SomeClient#getEntity` method** and have to cover all scenarios. For instance, I need to cover the scenario where there are exceptions thrown by `cacheWrapper`. The approach I'm following is to create a mock for `CacheWrapper` class, make the methods on `CacheWrapper` class to throw a `RuntimeException`, set this mock in an instance of `SomeClient` and test `Someclient#getEntity`. The problem is when trying to mock `putInSharedMemory` method because is `void`. I have tried lot of ways to do this but none of them work. **The project has dependencies for PowerMock and EasyMock**.

Here are my attempts:

1. Using `EasyMock.<Void>expect`. This raised a compiler error.
2. Tried to stub `CacheWrapper#putInSharedMemory`. Didn't worked because raised an exception with this error message:

   > java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call putInSharedMemory("foo", com.company.domain.Entity@609fc98)
3. **Added Mockito dependency to the project** to make use of the functionality of `PowerMockito` class. But this raised an exception because it doesn't integrate with EasyMock. This is the exception raised:

   > java.lang.ClassCastException: org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl cannot be cast to org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocationcontrol.MockitoMethodInvocationControl

Here's the code for this unit test sample:

```
@Test
public void getEntityWithCacheWrapperException() {
    CacheWrapper cacheWrapper = mockThrowsException();
    SomeClient someClient = new SomeClient();
    someClient.setCacheWrapper(cacheWrapper);
    Entity entity = someClient.getEntity();
    //here.....................^
    //cacheWrapper.putInSharedMemory should throw an exception

    //start asserting here...
}

//...

public CacheWrapper mockThrowsException() {
    CacheWrapper cacheWrapper = PowerMock.createMock(CacheWrapper.class);
    //mocking getFromSharedMemory method
    //this works like a charm
    EasyMock.expect(cacheWrapper.getFromSharedMemory(EasyMock.anyObject()))
        .andThrow(new RuntimeException("This is an intentional Exception")).anyTimes();

    //mocking putInSharedMemory method
    //the pieces of code here were not executed at the same time
    //instead they were commented and choose one approach after another

    //attempt 1: compiler exception: <Void> is not applicable for <void>
    EasyMock.<Void>expect(cacheWrapper.putInSharedMemory(EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject()))
        .andThrow(new RuntimeException("This is an intentional Exception")).anyTimes();

    //attempt 2: stubbing the method
    //exception when executing the test:
     //Unexpected method call putInSharedMemory("foo", com.company.domain.Entity@609fc98)
    Method method = PowerMock.method(CacheWrapper.class, "putInSharedMemory", Object.class, Object.class);
    PowerMock.stub(method).toThrow(new RuntimeException("Exception on purpose."));

    //attempt 3: added dependency to Mockito integrated to PowerMock
    //bad idea: the mock created by PowerMock.createMock() belongs to EasyMock, not to Mockito
    //so it breaks when performing the when method
    //exception:
    //java.lang.ClassCastException: org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl
    //cannot be cast to org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocationcontrol.MockitoMethodInvocationControl
    //at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:54)
    PowerMockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException("Exception on purpose."))
        .when(cacheWrapper).putInSharedMemory(EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject());

    PowerMock.replay(cacheWrapper);
    return cacheWrapper;
}
```

I cannot change the implementation of `CacheWrapper` because it comes from a third party library. Also, I cannot use `EasyMock#getLastCall` because I'm performing the test on `SomeClient#getEntity`.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Why do you need PowerMockito at all? None of your tested classes are final, you could just use a `spy()` over an instantiated instance... (you _can_ stub spies). Also, where does that .replay() come from?

Comment: @fge I'm not very skilled using any of these frameworks because I tend to write integration tests rather than pure unit tests. Please could you expand more about this `spy()` method or any relevant doc?

Comment: All in all the testing code is really bizarre, you seem to be using both easymock and (power)mockito... Any reason why?

Comment: @fge added powermockito just because it offered another solution, but as noted in attempt 3, it's a bad idea :)

Comment: Well, for instance, with pure mockito, you can do `final Foo foo = spy(new Foo()); doThrow(something).when(foo).someMethod(blah)`

Comment: Well, see my answer, it may contain some hits. You're an integration test specialist, I'm a unit test freak :p If you need more help, pleasr tell

Comment: OK, hold on. What is the code of your `CacheWrapper`'s `.put()` method? It seems to me that this is what you really want to test, isn't it? You can spy `SomeClient` and make it behave the way you want. And it seems that what you want to do really is not to test `.putInSharedMemory()`. I'm rather confused.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since none of your classes are final, you can use "pure mockito" without resorting to PowerMockito:

```
final CacheWrapper wrapper = Mockito.spy(new CacheWrapper());

Mockito.doThrow(something)
    .when(wrapper).putInSharedMemory(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any());
```

Note that "method arguments" to a stub are in fact argument matchers; you can put specific values (if not "surrounded" by a specific method it will make a call to `.equals()`). So, you can guide the stub's behavior differently for different arguments.

Also, no need for any kind of `.replay()` with Mockito, which is very nice!

Finally, be aware that you can `doCallRealMethod()` as well. After that, it depends on your scenarios...

(note: last mockito version available on maven is 1.10.17 FWIW)

Answer (score 6):

Are you using EasyMock or Mockito? Both are different frameworks.

PowerMockito is a superset (or more of a supplement) that can be used with both these frameworks. PowerMockito allows you to do things that Mockito or EasyMock don't.

Try this for stubbing void methods to throw exceptions:

**EasyMock:**

```
// First make the actual call to the void method.
cacheWrapper.putInSharedMemory("key", "value");
EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

Check:

- http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/internal/MocksControl.html#andVoid--
- [Getting EasyMock mock objects to throw Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027533/)

**Mockito:**

```
 // Create a CacheWrapper spy and stub its method to throw an exception.
 // Syntax for stubbing a spy's method is different from stubbing a mock's method (check Mockito's docs).
 CacheWrapper spyCw = spy(new CacheWrapper()); 
 Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException())
     .when(spyCw)
     .putInSharedMemory(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any());

 SomeClient sc = new SomeClient();
 sc.setCacheWrapper(spyCw);

 // This will call spyCw#putInSharedMemory that will throw an exception.
 sc.getEntity("key");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`expectLastCall`](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#expectLastCall--), like:

```
    cacheWrapper.putInSharedMemory(EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.anyObject())
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException("This is an intentional Exception")).anyTimes();
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry.

Comment: This throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available`. I'm testing `SomeClient#getEntity`, not `CacheWrapper`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza OK, I misunderstood; so, you mean to make .getEntity() throw an exception and catch that?