# Exception test for service layer

Tags: java, exception, testing

I have a class that looks like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public void removeOne(Long id) throws DataAccessException {
        bookRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

My exception tests looks like this

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void removeOneThrowsNullPointerException() {
    BookService foo = new BookServiceImpl();

    exception.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    foo.removeOne(1L);
}
```

Now this tests passes but first why must the BookService class be instantiated and normally this test would pass if was a simple unit test because we have a book with id 1L but now its a null, I have read articles on @Rule, what is actually going on? and is this a proper test for finding exception in the method removeOne()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have `NullPointerException` on the `bookRepository` in your service. By other word it is not autowired properly. Did you try to debug this test to see what exactly object is null?

There are 2 possible ways to write correct tests:

1. For integration testing you need to care about autowire all dependencies, read about `Spring` and testing.
2. For pure unit testing you need to care about mocking of all dependencies.

The usage of @Rule is correct way to test exceptional cases.

**UPDATE:**
The simplest way to test exceptional cases for service layer is to mock your repository class to throw the `DataAccessException` and inject it into the service class:

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void removeOneThrowsDataAccessException() {
    BookRepository mockedRepository = Mock(BookRepository.class);
    when(mockedRepository.get(1L)).thenThrow(new DataAccessException());

    BookService foo = new BookServiceImpl(mockedRepository);

    exception.expect(DataAccessException.class);

    foo.removeOne(1L);
}
```

Comment: my question is not about null pointer , this occures when we dont have an empty instance or variable , but normally i was given a task to write exception test for about 10 service logic that are working correctly , so how is that i should return an exception in this test ? also i am testing the scenario where i gave a null parameter to a method

Comment: The simplest way to test exceptional cases for service layer is to mock your repository class to throw the `DataAccessException` and inject it into service class.

Comment: can you show a code snippet on what u mean thank you

Comment: See the updated my post.

Comment: could not import the Mock u used in test @Dmytro maslenko

Comment: You could not import due of technical issue(s) or not allowed by manager?

Comment: i have an easy mock and a mockito dependency tried to import it says cannot resolve method, and also sinice removeOne method is void it doesnt accept a thenThrow statement @Dmytro maslenko

Comment: Use only one framework, say, easymock. For void methods look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866181/how-can-i-mock-a-void-method-to-throw-an-exception.

Comment: im using one but not able to perform Mock(BookRepo.class)

Comment: You should understand that my code may be not compilable. I gave an idea and if something couldn't be compiled try to fix it in your project. Instead of `Mock` try `Mockito.mock()`, etc.

Comment: yes you right , first i created an annonymous class for DataAccesException which i think worked fined in creating the mock but i wasnt able to pass mocked repository in to instance of service class as u did , so i didnt , i ran the test and it gave a null pointer exception

Comment: BookService foo = new BookServiceImpl(mockedRepository); not able to perfrom this and this is what makes the call return an exception because we have injected an exception to it Dmytro maslenko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165012/discussion-between-dmytro-maslenko-and-valik).