# Expect to throw exception without certain message

Tags: java, junit, easymock

For example I've got a method and I want to test case when it throws certain exception type. There's no constructor without parameters in `MyException` class.

```
public class Clazz {

    private Service service;

    public void method() {
        try {
            int result = service.perform();
        } catch (MyException exc) {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
}
```

I created mock for service and set it into Clazz instance.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    clazz = new Clazz();
    service = createStrictMock(Service.class);
    clazz.setService(service);
}
```

How should test look like? I mean how the test method for `method` should look like?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
expect(service.perform()).andThrow(new MyException(/* some params */));
```

For more details go to [documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html) (Working with Exceptions) or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027533/getting-easymock-mock-objects-to-throw-exceptions)

Because you rethrow exception you may also want to add `@Test(expected=MyException.class)` to the test method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following (assuming your `@setup` works)

```
@Test(expected = MyException.class)
public void testExceptionThrown() throws Exception(){
    Clazz subject = new Clazz();
    subject.setService(service);
    subject.method();
}
```