# How to use EasyMock annotation in Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm trying to use easyMock annotation for mocking methods. Please find below sample code.

Issue im facing is while using mock annotation, i believe by default the method gets mocked all the time. But i have two different method to be mocked. One at try block and another method at catch block(when i dont mock student method, it fails and goes into catch block).

But as Student method is being mocked all the time its not going inside catch block. Hence teacher method doesn't get covered.

Could anyone please help me understand what am i missing here? How does Mock annotation and createMock() method works? Does both work in different ways?

**Actual Class**

```
 @Autowire
 Student std;
 
 @Autowire
 Teacher teach;

public void handleClass() {
 try {
  std.callMethodToGetName();
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
  teach.informToTeacher();
 }
}
```

**TestClass**

```
 @Mock
 Student std;
 
 @Mock
 Teacher teach;

 @TestSubject
 ClassImpl testSub = new ClassImpl();

@Test
public void handleClassTestMethodStd() {
  std.callMethodToGetName();
 EasyMock.expectLastCall();
 testSub.handleClass();
}

@Test
public void handleClassTestMethodTeach() {
 teach.informToTeacher();
 EasyMock.expectLastCall();
 testSub.handleClass();
}
```

```
**Student Class**
Public void callMethodToGetName() {
    String abc = "hiii hello biee";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting EasyMock mock objects to throw Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027533/getting-easymock-mock-objects-to-throw-exceptions)

Comment: No, suggested post explains about handling exception in mock. In my example I have a method to be mocked inside catch block. How to mock that?

Comment: In your second test, don't you want the mocked std.callMethodToGetName invocation to throw an exception, so that teach.informToTeacher() is called?

Comment: I tried using andThrow(),, but dint work. What is happening is Mock annotation is created at start of classTest hence the object gets mocked. While debugging handleClassTestMethodTeach() method, in main class std.callMethodToGetName() gets mocked due to Mock annotation and it never comes to catch block.

Comment: callMethodToGetName() is meant to be mocked, but you need to make the mock invocation throw an exception. What do you mean by "didn't work"? Show the code you tried.

Comment: @Test
public void handleClassTestMethodTeach() {
 std.callMethodToGetName();
 EasyMock.expectLastCall().andThrow(new RuntimeException());
 testSub.handleClass();
}

Comment: But it didn't went inside catch block

Answer (score 0):

EasyMock has 3 phases: record, replay, verify. At the beginning you are in the recording phase. Where you set a behavior to your mock. Then you go in the replay phase. Where the mock is used and the test happens. Finally, you verify to make sure all expected calls where done. The last phase is not mandatory but useful. In your case, you are calling void methods. So making sure they were called make sense.

During the record phase, `expectLastCall()` is optional. Any void method will be recorded just by calling it.

So, a fully working test for your use-case would be the following:

```
public class ClassImplTest extends EasyMockSupport {

    @Rule
    public EasyMockRule rule = new EasyMockRule(this);

    @Mock
    private Student std;

    @Mock
    private Teacher teach;

    @TestSubject
    private ClassImpl testSub = new ClassImpl();

    @Test
    public void handleClassTestMethodStd() {
        std.callMethodToGetName();

        // Put in replay mode
        replayAll();

        testSub.handleClass();

        // Make sure all expected calls where actually done
        verifyAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void handleClassTestMethodTeach() {
        std.callMethodToGetName();
        expectLastCall().andThrow(new Exception("test"));
        teach.informToTeacher();

        Exception actual = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> testSub.handleClass());
        assertEquals("test", actual.getMessage());

        verifyAll();
    }

}
```

Note that I am using `EasyMockSupport` to make my life easier. But we can also call `EasyMock.replay(std, teach)` and `EasyMock.verify(std, teach)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm getting error while running test at --- Exception actual = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> testSub.handleClass()); this line throws error -- "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: last method called on mock cannot throw java.lang.ExceptIon"

Comment: Try using a RuntimeException instead (without seeing the code of your Student class it isn't possible to say exactly which exception you should be throwing and expecting)

Comment: I tried using RuntimeException, test ran without any error. But it dint went inside catch block. Std object got mocked, instead of throwing exception

Comment: Not possible if you have `expectLastCall().andThrow(new Exception("test"));` unless  `callMethodToGetName()` is not final or `std` is really the mocked instance.